# Getting $rootScope:inprog error when calling click method of input type file programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to  create custom file upload component .  I did  following code  in html

*HTML CODE*

```
<input id="upload" type="file" style="display: none;">// don`t want to render default
<button class="parimarybtnVD" type="button" ng-click="clickUpload()">Browse</button>
```

*JS CODE*

```
$scope.clickUpload = function() {
    angular.element('#upload').trigger('click');
};
```

But  getting  following error  when I clicked 'button'.

```
           Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
at Error (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:7001/RightsWeb/scripts/resource/angular.min.js:6:450
at l (http://localhost:7001/RightsWeb/scripts/resource/angular.min.js:102:171)
at h.$digest (http://localhost:7001/RightsWeb/scripts/resource/angular.min.js:105:497)
at HTMLDocument.D (http://localhost:7001/RightsWeb/scripts/utill/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js:9:14775)
at HTMLDocument.f.event.dispatch (http://localhost:7001/RightsWeb/extResources/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3:4351)
at HTMLDocument.h.handle.i (http://localhost:7001/RightsWeb/extResources/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3:328)
at Object.f.event.trigger (http://localhost:7001/RightsWeb/extResources/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3:3038)
at <error: TypeError: Accessing selectionDirection on an input element that cannot have a selection.>
at Function.e.extend.each (http://localhost:7001/RightsWeb/extResources/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2:11937)
```

Could  anyone tell me  why I am  getting  this  error ? If there  is  better way of  doing  custom  file  upload  in angularjs please tell .Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In angular at any point in time there can be only one `$digest` or `$apply` operation in progress.

Use `$timeout`.

```
$scope.clickUpload = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        angular.element('#upload').trigger('click');
    }, 1);
};
```

OR, I would suggest you to use

```
<button 
    class="parimarybtnVD" 
    type="button" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('upload').click()">Browse</button>
```

Comment: Second  approach  worked for me. but for  first  i am getting $timeout  undefined .I am  using 1.2.16. please let  me  do I need to include some  other file  for '$timeout'

Comment: You need to inject `$timeout` in your controller

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I faced the same problem, and I would like to offer another solution, although the `$timeout` solution worked for me as well. In general, I don't like to use it unless it's absolutely necessary; and in this case it really isn't.

This apply error here happens because when you call the `angular.element('#upload').trigger('click');` method inside the `clickUpload` method, angularjs hasn't finished the digest cycle until the function returns, but we go ahead and perform another click programmatically which triggers another digest, so basically, the only thing we need to do is wait for the digest to finish (which is kind of what the $timeout does except it does that because it lets the method return before initiating the click), this can be done using `$scope.$$postDigest`

Which means changing the code to the following:

```
$scope.clickUpload = function() {
    $scope.$$postDigest(function() {
        angular.element('#upload').trigger('click');
    });
};
```

In my opinion it is the cleaner approach, because the `$scope.$$postDigest` is designated to wait for the current digest cycle whereas `$timeout` solves the issue because it runs the click after the `clickUpload` returns